# ML assignment operation

Tags: sml, smlnj, ml

everyone, what is difference between the following assignments in ML,

```
val n = 5;
```

and

```
n := 1;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The former is a declaration of a new, immutable variable. The latter is how you re-assign the value of a reference cell.