# Why using the equality sign in an assignment of a constant?

Tags: eiffel

I have a question concerning constants in eiffel. Well it's just a semantic issue but it has been bugging me for some time now and I just don't understand the concept of this speciality.

For a normal assignment you use `:=` which makes total sense in a mathematical thinking because it's the mathematical sign for an assignment

But if we look at the definition of a constant:

```
feature
    some_constant: INTEGER = 5
```

I just don't see why we use the equality sign there. Is there a certain reason? I would understand it the following way: We assign the value 5 to the constant but then why the boolean expression?

I hope someone can explain the concept behind this

Comment: Ask Bertrand -- he has likely written a paper (or two) on the syntax choice. I suspect it's because in a constant it's **not** "mutating a cell" (assigning a value to a variable) but rather establishing a definition. That is, in a way, it's similar to bindings (`=`) and mutating assignments (`:=`) in languages like SML ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168889/ml-assignment-operation)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it still doesn't make sense ;) I mean whats the mathematical sign for a definition? Yes its `:=`... I'll probably write him an email...  now I've seen your edit. Thanks for clearifying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to treat the `=` sign as a quick contract for the constant feature.

```
foo: INTEGER = 5
```

would be identical to

```
foo: INTEGER
  ensure
    Result = 5
```

Note that this is a recent syntax change, before it used to be

```
foo: INTEGER is 5
```

but the Eiffel specification dropped the `is` keyword altogether.